# React Class is not being generated

Tags: reactjs

You completed the following configuration:

1. npm run eject run this command inside  project root directory.
2. search cssRegex and add the following lines under  `use: getStyleLoaders({`

   ```
   modules:true,
   localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]
   ```

Now I just test the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import classes from './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className={classes.App}>
       <p>hello</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As far i did,  `<div className={classes.App}>` this should be converted as like this: `<div class="APP_local_ANYTHING">`. But no class is being generated. Whats wrong is going on?

Comment: is your app bootstrapped with ReactDOM.render method?

Comment: I am not sure about that. How can I check this? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

if that's all the code you've got, app is not bootstrapped. In order to do so, you would have to add the folowing piece of code:

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from 'app'; // file with you App component

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')) // or any other selector in HTML you want to have your app attached to.
```

[Simple Codepen example](https://codepen.io/adamkosmala/pen/oJKaYG)